# How to isolate what is changing `set noshowmode` to `showmode` upon startup?

Tags: vimrc

In my .vimrc file I have
`set noshowmode`

However, upon starting vim, `:set noshowmode?` returns `showmode`.

Something must be adjusting this setting upon startup (perhaps a plugin?). What's the best way to go about diagnosing something like this?

For the record, I've tried starting vim with the following command:
`vim -V9verbose.log` but for some reason it still outputs the results to the command line rather than to the named file. I have to quit vim to save myself from being caught in a seemingly never ending verbose hell. Am I not using that command properly?

Thank you in advance for any help, please let me know if you need any more info!

Comment: `:verbose set showmode?` will tell you where it was last set from.

Comment: B Layer, that should be an answer.

Comment: @Spidey You have a point. Will create an answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to run the following:

```
:verbose set showmode?
```

This should tell you from where the option was last set.

For many command types prepending `:verbose` is the same as [setting `'verbose'` to 1](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3Averbose-cmd) and...

> ...when 'verbose' is non-zero, **listing the value of a Vim option** or a key map or an abbreviation or a user-defined function or a command or a highlight group or an autocommand **will also display where it was last defined**.  If it was defined manually then there will be no "Last set" message.  When it was defined while executing a function, user command or autocommand, the script in which it was defined is reported.

If this doesn't help for some reason then some general advice can be found in [How do I debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file). (E.g. if you want to rule out any plugins as the cause.)

---

As for your use of `-V` that looks perfectly fine to me. You might want to check that you have file system permissions set up correctly to allow the Vim process to create/write a file in that directory and/or make sure there isn't already a file with that name with restricted permissions. That's all I can think of at this point. Oh, and use `-V1` rather than `-V9` while you're trying to figure it out. :)

Comment: Thank you B Layer! In my instance, this helped me narrow it down to the vim-workspace plugin. For some reason my .vimrc's `set nowshowmode` was being overridden by the plugin. In order to fix the issue, I had to configure the plugin with the following line: `let g:workspace_nocompatible = 0`

Comment: @Spectator6 Glad it helped.